# Interchanging the date header with time side bar in calendar in odoo

Tags: fullcalendar, odoo, odoo-9

How to interchange the date and time in calendar ? the functions of date is in line no. 3092 from where the date is comming in the header portion of calendar and the functions of time is in line no. 2999 from where the time is comming in the side bar of the calendar in fullcalendar.js file in odoo

Comment: you can extend the calendar js in your new module or create a new js for that you can refer this link for header set in calendar   http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/